# Rejecting suggested edit is broken

Tags: bug

Rejecting a suggested edit on a question page pops up the reason dialog behind the reject dialog, making it impossible to reject an edit this way.

[image: reject edit]

Has this changed recently? I've never had a problem doing this before.

---

I'm using Chrome 58.0.

Comment: Whoops. There was already a post for this. Sorry.